# Big O notation In this context

Tags: algorithm, big-o, privacy, little-o

I’m reading a book and I came accorss this statement

> We finally define what it means for an algorithm to be non-private. blatantly Non private Definition 1. An algorithm is blatantly non-private if an adversary can construct a database c 2 {0, 1}n such that it matches the true database d in all but o(n) entries.

which I understand since o(n) can mean <= c*g(x) and it’s true for all  c so c can be 0.001 which will mean very small number of entries like <= 0.001n entries.
the next theorem is this

> Theorem 2 ([DN03]). If the analyst is allowed to ask 2n subset queries, and the curator adds noise with some bound E, then based on the results, the adversary can reconstruct the database in all but 4E positions.

I completely understand this one too but after proving this theorem the author wrote

> if the analyst is able to ask 2n queries with noise bounded by O(n), then then the adversary can reconstruct (essentially) the entire database.

from above E is `E=O(n)`

I’m at complete loss here If the above is true and by definition of Big-0 ins’t the value of E will be close to n or something big since O(n) and if yes than how can we reconstruct the dataset at all if we can’t reconstruct 4E entries? I'm not sure what O(n) will be here?

I tried looking into books and online asked my friends and all couldn't find an answer

Comment: Note: if E=O(n), then 4E is still the same complexity. O(n) doesn't mean `n`, it means "kn, where k is some constant". O(4n) is the same as O(1,000,000n) is the same as O(n). It's the `n` that determines the runtime complexity in the limit.

Comment: I think it indicates that the noise grows linearly with n, and despite that, the "adversary"  can still reconstruct a large part of the database, except for a few positions affected by the noise.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was wondering if we have following: f(n) = E, g(n) =n and for constant k = 1/2 in this case we make n/2 errors e.g f(n) <= c*g(n) which means E <= 1/2*n which essentially means we can't reconstruct half the dataset?